# Setting Style Width/Height using function HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this in the body:

```
<div id="map"style="width: 400; height: 400" ></div>
```

I tried creating a variable and updating it like this:

```
<div id="map"style="width: map_size; height: map_size" ></div>
```

I also tried creating a function as well as setting it another way:

```
function getComboA(sel) {
    map_size = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;  
    $("#map").css("width", map_size);
    $("#map").css("height",map_size);
```

I *attempted* to get the value for map_size from a drop down menu, I'm not sure how to test if it's working correctly but the map is not showing up.

I'm new to this so I'm probably misunderstanding something basic, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I created a demo here..

http://jsfiddle.net/kN7UQ/2/

Is this helping?

**UPDATE**

```
$(function(){ //document ready... be sure to start your code after the document is ready

    $('select').bind('change', function(){ //this is binds to the 'change' event of the select box
        var dimension = $('select').val(); //here we are taking the selected value from the select box
        $('#map').css({ width: dimension +'px', height: dimension +'px' }); // this is where we are setting the dimension for the '#map' element, be sure to add 'px' to the dimension as i saw you didn't in your question
    });

});​
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I tried it in my code, can you explain the function that you posted? At which point does it reference the menu from which the value was selected?

Comment: Thank you, I'm still unclear though. Isn't the value of 'id' or the function set to be called for 'onchange' in the menu of any significance? What exactly is the 'change' event? I have several drop down menu boxes, how does the function know which one's input to process?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the values of our variables in Javascript before the script will recognize them. If they are .Net variables, then it won't recognize them, they're two indepenant systems. The following articles may help you bridge the two systems:

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/net_discoveries/archive/2012/08/30/Using-ASP.Net-to-Create-JavaScript-Code.aspx

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/net_discoveries/archive/2007/01/05/Using-ASP.Net-to-Create-JavaScript-Variables.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

http://jsfiddle.net/vXHLS/1/